# If the user selects the dev or tst environment, they are only permitted to deploy the region to central

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

```
trigger:
  - none

pool:
  name: Ubuntu-Latest
parameters:
  - name: environment
    displayName: CWP environment
    type: string
    default: Please select environment
    #template: ArmTemplate
    values:
      - Please select environment
      - dev
      - stg
      - tst
  - name: region
    displayName: CWP Region
    type: string
    default: Please select environment Central or East
    values:
      - central
      - east
      - both
```

Comment: Please format code and add detailed question in the post because the issue is unclear at this moment

Comment: Is this a YAML pipeline or classic release?

Comment: This is Yaml Pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have conditional parameter values. The best you can do is have a `script` step that examines the selected parameters and fails the pipeline if an invalid combination of parameters is selected.

This sort of problem is more commonly solved by using multiple *stages* in your pipeline, one stage for each environment.

Comment: After the region parameter I have added this line but even though its failing - script: |
    if [ "$(environment)" == "dev" ] && [ "$(region)" == "east" ]; then
      echo "Invalid combination: Dev environment cannot be deployed to the East region."
      exit 1
    elif [ "$(environment)" == "tst" ] && [ "$(region)" == "both" ]; then
      echo "Invalid combination: TST environment cannot be deployed to both regions."
      exit 1
      fi

Comment: @vikashsharma That's because you're trying to access parameters using macro syntax for variables. Variables and parameters are not the same thing. You should specify an `env` block and map your parameters as environment variables for your `script` step with the appropriate compilation-time syntax, i.e. `${{ parameters.environment }}`.

Comment: Yes, It was a typo mistake I did, but yes I am providing parameters.environment and parameters.region but still the pipeline is running when I am deploying in east region of dev and tst.

Comment: @vikashsharma It sounds like you have a new question, then. However, please do consider what I said about using stages. You can choose a stage to deploy at queue time.